# Distinct select query in MySQL that fetches all the rows with value NULL and 1 but not 0

Tags: mysql

Table:

```
Id   user_id   mail   notification
1    23        A      0
2    23        A      1
3    23        A      NULL
4    28        A      0
5    28        A      0
6    28        A      NULL
7    28        A      0
8    29        A      0
9    29        A      0
```

---

```
select distinct user_id from table where notification!=0;
```

I want the result to be 23 and 28 but not 29. (ie., `user_id`'s for which notification is `1` and `NULL` and not `0`) as a distinct result.

Would you please suggest me a way?

Comment: and this: select distinct user_id from table where notification!=0 does not work?

Comment: You don't have `27` in your example, also, `28` has `0` and `NULL` and not `1` , which is the opposite of what you said. Please rephrase the question.

Comment: Sorry that is 23 i have edited now

Comment: !=0 does not take the null value, i mean it only brings result with notification value 1

Comment: Do you mean "1 OR NULL"?

Comment: They all have 0 as a result. So the desired result is an empty set.

Comment: I want the user id's with notification 1 or null and not 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add `OR notification IS NULL`:

```
select distinct user_id 
from table1 
where notification != 0 OR notification IS NULL;
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/368b3f/2)